# Delete multiple rows while using the id from the row before

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a folder and file system in my database.

And while deleting the folders **with** the subfolder, it should also delete the corresponding files in the folder from my other table (files_plus). But how can i delete both the folder, it's subfolder and all files contained in the folder and subfolders?

Table: files_plus:

```
-----------------------------
| id  |  name  |  parentid  |
-----------------------------
```

(the "parentid" being the "id" from the folders_plus table.)

Table: folders_plus

[image: SQL Table example]

I can't think of any way to construct a query for doing so, so how would i manage to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a foreign key constraint and set it on "CASCADE DELETE" like this for the `folders_plus` table.

```
ALTER TABLE `folders_plus` 
ADD INDEX `folders_plus_parentid_idx` (`parentid` ASC);
ALTER TABLE `folders_plus` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_folders_plus_id_folders_plus_parentid`
  FOREIGN KEY (`parentid`)
  REFERENCES `folders_plus` (`id`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

And for the `files_plus` table:

```
ALTER TABLE `files_plus` 
ADD INDEX `fk_files_plus_id_folders_plus_parentid_idx` (`parentid` ASC);
ALTER TABLE `files_plus` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_files_plus_id_folders_plus_parentid`
  FOREIGN KEY (`parentid`)
  REFERENCES `folders_plus` (`id`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

When you delete a parent row, it will also delete all of it's children.

Do make sure that your `parentid` column is nullable, and that every top level directory is null. Every parentid that is not null, is required to exist as an id in your `folders_plus` table.

<sub>PS: Please do note that in order for foreign key constraints to work, your [database storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-engines.html) should be InnoDB.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

1. Make userid and parentid the same type (I'm guessing INT (10) UNSIGNED )
2. Allow a NULL value to parentid
3. UPDATE table SET parentid = NULL WHERE parentid = 0
4. Create a foreign key from parentid to userid
5. When creating the foreign key set "ON DELETE" to "CASCADE" - this will cause all items that have a parentID that has been deleted to also be deleted.